# Using Azure Mobile Services Offline Sync with Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, azure-mobile-services, azure-blob-storage, typescript-typings

I'm rewriting an app that is done in Ionic 1 to Ionic 2. Old code base done 100% HTTP gets/ posts which gives a very bad UX with data saving and retrieving. The goal integrate new Ionic 2 app with offline sync data/ blob (pictures) with Azure mobile service with sql server db back end (which is already done).

So far I have tried

**Azure Cordova Plugin**
I followed Adrian Hall's documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-cordova-get-started-offline-data) and manage to get around somewhat working example in Ionic 1 but not 2.

**JavaScript Client Library**
I even followed Richard Shergold's blog post (https://ionicallyspeaking.com/2016/10/11/ionic-2-and-azure/) and manage to get a working example of retrieving data from Ionic 2 but didn't manage to get around for offline syncing bits.

Biggest gap is the there is no available typings for the current library. As per to the team its in the pipeline. (https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client/issues/79)

Has anyone gone beyond that? It's very limited hep out their in the community :9 Could someone help me out by directing me to a working example of how to enable offline sync with Ionic 2 app.

All my code snippets are same as what is in the links above. I am not asking without trying. I really need some help. Please!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-mobile-cordova-client-conflict-handling is a Cordova sample that demonstrates how to use offline sync and how to handle conflicts, if any. This should be a good reference for your Ionic application.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. I had a look at your repo when I did an example in Ionic 1, but I am particularly looking for integrating the same for Ionic 2 and like I said the difficulty I am finding in Ionic 2 is integrating/ referring azure in my Ionic 2 which uses type script.

Comment: I see. Adding type definitions has been on our backlog. Have you taken a look at the API reference at https://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-js-client/? This can be a useful reference in the short term in the absence of type definitions.

Comment: Thanks for the link it sure will be helpful. I have seen people start writing up their own *.d.ts for the module but don't wont to rely on them since its not official. But I am sure if you guys give a start we can contribute writing the definitions.

Comment: I've been successfully using Azure App Service with offline sync and Ionic 2 for several months now.  I have to manually reference MobileServices.Cordova.js in my index.html file and then manually declare the object WindowsAzure.  It's far from ideal, but it does work.

Comment: @CoreyRoth can you give a code snippet or a plunkr on how you got this all to work?